# Octave error: invalid conversion of uint8 matrix to Matrix

Tags: matrix, octave

## NewToOctave

I wrote down the following code:

```
 imgnew = imread('C:\Users\vijay kant chadha\Downloads\earth.jpg');
```

//The following line's execution shows error

```
 imshow(imgnew);

 //error: invalid conversion of uint8 matrix to Matrix
```

Please help me for the same... :)

Comment: What version of Octave? See http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?45372

Comment: Thanks a lot !! :)